# Checking if a timestamp is in a given range using Laravel 6

Tags: sql, laravel

within my base before scheduling a new appointment. The main problem is that I don't know how to know if a given date  (timestamp) is in a given range.
I have $start_date and $end_date as entries and I need to check wether the appointment date retrieved from the base is within that range or not

[image: Table DAtes]

[image: Data]

`SELECT * FROM dates WHERE what_date ='2020-01-29 15:24:25' and start_time BETWEEN '22:13:00' and '21:13:00'`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a whereTime() method for the query builder. There is no "between" for this particular method so you'll need two comparisons

```
$query->whereTime('start_time', '>=', $start_time)
      ->whereTime('start_time', '<=' , $end_time)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't do it the way you did but your answer inspired me and here is how I fixed it. `Dates::where('what_date','like','%'.$data['what_date'].'%')->whereTime('start_time', '>=', $start_time)->whereTime('start_time', '<=' , $left_time)->get();`